# Rails beginner help with making a custom order form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

So what I basically would like to do is make an order form. In this order form, users will submit information about their company members, and there will also be a part at the end of the order form where the user can select option services that are added by my client from a backend. I am new to rails so I would just like someone to help me make sure that I am going to do this using the best possible practice. Here is what I think I need to do:

1. Make an Order model
2. Make a Member model
3. Make a Field model

In my order model make

```
has_many :members
has_many :fields
```

In my member model make `belongs_to :order` and in my field model make `belongs_to :order`. Then what I need to do in my orders controller is `@fields = Field.all` and extract it in a `@fields.each` block.

P.S. there is one other thing I have to do and that is to make the order form displays 3 types of headers: Corporation, LLC, and Non-profit. What I thought would be smart is if in the url I made it like `type=1` and `type=2` and `type=3` and in my model use an if statement like:

```
def order_type(type)
   if type === "1"
     "corporation"
   elsif type === "2"
     "llc"
   else
     "nonprofit"
  end
end
```

I think using an if statement is kinda sloppy so for that so if someone could please explain to me the best practice that would be great. Please don't try and answer with a railscasts episode because I have checked out a lot of them already. What I would like is an explanation if possible

Thanks guys it means a lot

Answer (score 0):

Are your fields really so complicated that they require their own model? If your "fields" are a one column list just include them as a column in the model they are applied too.

The problem with using the URL method that you suggested is as follows.  Say a user creates a model object and assigns it as a "LLC.". Then your URL would have type=1 somewhere in it as you suggested. Now a user bookmarks this URL and afterwards someone realized it was a typo and instead of LLC the heading should be something else. Now you have a unRESTful situation where you are creating dead links on the Internet or you have urls that are encoded.   URL encoding should be used for querying data not dceciding what the data should be.

I would not mess with the urls for the heading question. Instead just add a heading field to the main model that will be displayed and have that field either be LLC etc.  Then in the view just have a variable that loads in the value for the object being displayed.

Comment: so basically i should have the header name determined by a post request? like for example, they click on a select box which order form they want and then it passes them to the order form without any indication if its a corp, llc, or nonprofit in the url?

Comment: It would be a GET request and if the header info is stored as part of the model you won't be making a separate request.  It's just another attribute to the object you are displaying.  You might use different templates to selectively display different fields but if the only difference between a llc or corp is the title text then you want a field on your attribute called "order_type". Users create a new order 'domain/order/new' and choose a type from a drop down and save it.  If the user only wants to see non profits it's easy to filter all of your orders by your 'order_type' column.